# accessing root.strings from settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am using settings bundle for my app. I could not access root.plist and root.strings file  of settings bundle from the following code.  Could anyone help?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *plist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Root" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *rootofplist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plist];
NSArray *preferenceitems = (NSArray *) [rootofplist valueForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

iPhone is case sensitive, try @"root" instead of @"Root"...

Comment: no..it is still returning nil..Have u tried to get string from root.strings from Settings.bundle?

Comment: try to check here: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file